# Combinatorica`PlanarQ doesn't work

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

```
 g1=Graph[{UndirectedEdge[a,b]}];
 GraphQ[g1]
 (*
   OUT: True
 *)
   (*Needs["Combinatorica`"]*)
 PlanarQ[g1]
 (*
    OUT: PlanarQ[.-.]
 *)
 Combinatorica`PlanarQ[g1]
 (*
   OUT: Combinatorica`PlanarQ[.-.]
 *)
```

Why doesn't PlanarQ give back "True" or "False" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your graph is not a `Combinatorica` graph, rather it is a `System` graph.  You'll need to specify the contexts explicitly.

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
g1 = System`Graph[{UndirectedEdge[a, b]}];
Combinatorica`PlanarQ[
  GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph[g1]]
```

This returns `True` but, in general, this process is a pain and rather buggy.  I believe that `Combinatorica` is on the way out and I'd recommend trying to get by without.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

cg1 = ToCombinatoricaGraph[g1];

PlanarQ[cg1]
```

I don't have v8 to check, however.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, Combinatorica is on the way out. However, three months ago a lead on the Graph project told me there were no plans to re-implement algorithm specific interfaces like `BrelazColoring` for System Graph. So, some things may need `Combinatorica` for a while, and one way to deal with this is to try to use System'Graph for everything, keep `Combinatorica` out of package path, and get to Combinatorica functions by explicitly converting your Graph objects to Combinatorica'Graph objects, calling Combinatorica`function and then converting back to system graph. [Here is some discussion with the details](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/combinatorica%2420graph%2420author%3ayaroslav%2420author%3abulatov/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/PG8C-qQvXPI/6J4whGBLNIwJ)

For posterity, here's the `relabelGraph` function I use to solve the ordering issue reported by TomD,

```
relabelGraph[g_Graph,labeling_]:=Module[{vcoords,gstyle,labelMap,adjMat,newOrder,newCoords,verts},
    verts=VertexList@g;
    vcoords=VertexCoordinates/.AbsoluteOptions[g,VertexCoordinates];
    gstyle=GraphStyle/.AbsoluteOptions[g,GraphStyle];
    labelMap=Thread[Range[Length[verts]]->labeling];

    adjMat=Normal@AdjacencyMatrix[g];
    newOrder=Ordering[VertexList[g]/.labelMap];

    newCoords=Thread[(VertexList[g]/.labelMap)->vcoords];

    AdjacencyGraph[adjMat[[newOrder,newOrder]],VertexCoordinates->newCoords,GraphStyle->gstyle]
];
```

One way of using it is below. This produces result similar to `IndexGraph`, but with sorted `VertexList`

```
g=relabelGraph[g,Range@Length@VertexList@g];
```

Some other of my "annoyance fixing" functions are described in `graphUsage.nb` in the package [here](http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/03/graph-utilities-i-use.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is also just a note.

I want to specifically draw attention to a possible bug in `ToCombinatoricaGraph` and a possible workaround.  It may have no relevance to the original question.

Also, I am using Mma 7, so things may be fixed in v8.

If I define a graph as follows

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

gr1 = {2 -> 4, 4 -> 3, 3 -> 1}
```

**GraphPlot of gr1**

[image]

Compare the following:

```
EdgeList@gr1
EdgeList@ToCombinatoricaGraph@gr1
Edges@ToCombinatoricaGraph@gr1
```

*Output*

```
{{2, 4}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}
```

The workaround I use is to ignore, as far as is possible, `ToCombinatoricaGraph` and instead convert to a *Combinatorica* graph using `FromOrderedPairs`.

For example

```
Edges@FromOrderedPairs@EdgeList@gr1
EdgeList@FromOrderedPairs@EdgeList@gr1
```

*Output*

```
{{2, 4}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}
{{2, 4}, {3, 1}, {4, 3}}
```

Another example, `Degrees`

Compare

```
Degrees@MakeSimple@ToCombinatoricaGraph[gr1]
VertexList@MakeSimple@ToCombinatoricaGraph[gr1]
```

*Output*

```
{1, 2, 2, 1}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

with

```
Degrees@MakeSimple@FromOrderedPairs@EdgeList@gr1
VertexList@MakeSimple@FromOrderedPairs@EdgeList@gr1

{1, 1, 2, 2}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I'll also include an example with [Prufer codes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrueferCode.html), as here I was badly 'caught out' (I did not know about SO then)

```
LabeledTreeToCode@MakeSimple@ToCombinatoricaGraph@gr1
LabeledTreeToCode@MakeSimple@FromOrderedPairs@EdgeList@gr1
```

*Output*

```
{2, 3}
{3, 4}
```

(Only the second answer is correct)

I have reported this to Wolfram. Seemingly, it is connected to reordering of vertices on graph creation by `ToCombinatoricaGraph`.  Here is part of the reply (2009)

> The reason that Edges and EdgeList
>   don't function on ToCombinatoricaGraph
>       objects because the Combinatorica package was developed prior to these
>       functions, and the structure hasn't yet been adapted to operate
>   with these
>       functions.
>
> ```
> Our development team is currently working to update the Combinatorica
> package so that these functions will be compatible.  If you happen to
> ```
>
> run
>       across any other issues, or have any questions come up, please do let
>   me
>       know.

In my view, `ToCombinatoricaGraph` needs to be used with care (and avoided whenever possible). However, there are probably many cases (including the uses given in other answers to the original question) where it makes no difference.

Personally, I would not like to see the *Combinatorica* package go.  It contains many useful functions (if very badly documented).

Comment: I've ran into several bugs that were related to ordering of vertices. My workaround was to make sure VertexList@g is sorted. This also gives more natural AdjacencyMatrix, added example of how to do this in my answer